# @Mockbean doesn't work on a bean unsed on multiple classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-webflux

I have the follow context on my Application. One Component is used for two services an these services are used it for a third service. I would like to test the integration between these services so I use @MockBean to mock the response from the Component. On the First service the mock works and I got a response, but on the second service I always got a null from the Component.

Here is my Application Context.

```java
public class Service1 {
  @Autowired
  private Component component;

  public Mono<String> getText() {
     return component.getText()
               .flatMap(string-> string.toUpperCase());
  }
}
```

```java
public class Service2 {
  @Autowired
  private Component component;

  public Mono<String> getSubString() {
     // always got null from component here
     return component.getText()
                .flatMap(string-> string.substring(1,2));
  }
}
```

```java
public class Service3 {
  @Autowired
  private Service1 service1;
  @Autowired
  private Service2 service2;
  @Autowired
  private Repository repository;

  public Mono<String> getData() {
      Mono<String> text1 = service1.getText();
      Mono<String> subString = service2.getSubString();
      return Mono.zip(text1, subString).flatMap( tuple -> {
          return tuple.getT1(), tuple.getT2();
      }).onSuccess(string-> repository.save(string));
  }
}
```

```java
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class}, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ApplicationTest {

  @MockBean
  Component component;
  @Autowired
  Service3 service3;
  @Autowired
  Repository repository;

  @Test
  public testService3() {
    given(component.getText()).willReturn("abc");
    
    service.getData().subscribe();

    assertNotNull(repository.findAll());   
  }
}
```

I tried to mock with theses ways:

```java
 given(component.getText()).willReturn("abc").willReturn("def");
```

or

```java
 given(component.getText()).willReturn("abc","def");
```

How can I get response from Component on service1 and service2 using the same @MockBean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mock `Service1` and `Service2`, because `Component` is dependency of them, not `Service3`.

fix you code like this

```java
    @MockBean
    Service1 service1;

    @MockBean
    Service2 service2;

    //...

    given(service1.getText()).willReturn("abc");
    given(service2.getSubString()).willReturn("def");
```